# How can I verify that the Pauli group is a group? And is it abelian?

Tags: mathematics, pauli-gates

So how can I verify that the Pauli Group is a Group? Then furthermore, Abelian? And then to sum it up, the order of the group. Trying to do some research into the group but I can't find much about it.

Comment: What makes you think it’s abelian?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_group

Comment: Hasan how is that useful in anyway to what was asked?  Anyone can copy and paste a link from a wiki that literally explains nothing.

Comment: And Mark that's what I was asking, is it Abelian haha

Comment: Using the link @HasanIqbal gave you, you could count the number of elements in the set and multiply a few of them together to check if it were abelian or not. The link pretty much answers your question.

Comment: please stick to a single question per post. You can create multiple posts to ask multiple questions

Answer (score 3):

For the three Pauli matrices, {${\sigma_1,\sigma_2}=0$}, so certainly this can not form an abelian group. The Pauli group is an isomorphism with $D_4$.

The elements of the Pauli group are {${I, \sigma_x, \sigma_y, i\sigma_z, -I, -\sigma_x, -\sigma_y, -i\sigma_z}$}, so the order of this group is 8. In variant subgroups are {${I, -I}$}, {${I, -I, \sigma_{x/y}, -\sigma_{x/y}}$} and {${I, -I, i\sigma_z, -i\sigma_z}$}. $I$ and $-I$ is the only emelemt in its class. {$\pm\sigma_{x/y}$} and {$\pm i\sigma_z$} forms a class( totally 5 classes).
Order 1 element: $I$. Order 2 elements: $\sigma_x, \sigma_2, -I, -\sigma_x, -\sigma_y$. And Order 3 elements: $\pm i\sigma_z$.

To check that the upper set actually forms a group, you need to prove that the set satisfies the four properties of a group: closure, associativity, identity element, inverse element, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)) for more detail.

Here comes the group table of the Pauli group.

[image: Group table]

You can also see Wikipedia and check it is identical to the group table of $D_4$(in fact the tables are different because the ordering of elements is different).

Comment: Note that this is not always the definition of the Pauli group. E.g. Wiki and N&C gives a different definition. See this [QCSE answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6784/definition-of-the-pauli-group-and-the-clifford-group).

Comment: Yes, construct a Pauli group is my homework about 1 year ago and that time, I just did it by my self. But this is a group and the property should be quite alike(but when reading papers with the standard definition this surly might cause trouble).